# Thunar - Make the drag and drop menu pop up by default

Tags: xubuntu, thunar

In Thunar if I right-click while dragging a file rather than left-clicking it, a popup menu reminiscent of Dolphin's shows up, (see image below) giving me the option to move, copy, and link to the file that was dragged and dropped.

[image]

How can I make this the default behavior? (In other words, how can I make this menu pop up whenever I'm dragging and dropping with the left mouse button.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm reasonably sure this can only be achieved through a source code change.

Thunar does have custom actions (like Nautilus) but they only appear as context menu entries whereas you're trying to change under what circumstances an *entirely different* context menu is opened.

I'm not aware of any other plug-in system in Thunar.